# GWT deserialization Exception

Tags: gwt, deserialization, gwt-rpc

recently moved to windows 7 and upgraded GWT from get 2.2.0 to 2.4.0.

But an application which previously worked, throws this exception.

> WARNING: Getting VaR exec time Failed. env=PRE.
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: The
>   response could not be deserialized    at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:221)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>     at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException:
>   java.util.ArrayList/3821976829    at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.getTypeHandler(SerializerBase.java:153)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.instantiate(SerializerBase.java:114)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:111)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter$ResponseReader$8.read(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:106)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:214)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>     at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

I have seen questions about similar GWT problems, but it is not exactly similar to my issue.

I have checked that the synchronus and asynchronous interfaces plus the implementation class are compatible.

The method being invoked is

```
Date getSophisVarDumpTime(String environment);
```

The application uses GWT-RPC.

In hosted mode I stepped into the response deserialization to find the issue.

I Found that an entry in the deserialization map in SerializerBase.getTypeHandler() is .

```
java.sql.Date/730999118=com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.sql.Date_FieldSerializer
```

But the type information in the response is java.sql.Date/3996530531, so the deserialization routine is not found.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the application, but this has had no effect.

Not sure how these identifiers can be different.

any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

`java.sql.Date` can not be deserialized, you must replace this by `java.util.Date`.

Comment: i should stated that this is just an issue in hosted mode, if I deploy the war file everything works fine.

Comment: That is very strange... GWT does not have the sources for java.sql so instantiating a java.sql.Date cannot work.